# React Redux Axios Api Get call with path parameters

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, react-hooks

I am trying to do a axios get call to my backend server with path variable and save the response data to the store. Unfortunately it only works for the get call with no path variables. still I can also log the response in the console, but I am unable to dispatch the response.data to the store

```
fetchByCardNumber: (CardNumber) => axios.get(baseURL+'loyalty/loyaltyCustomer/card/'+ CardNumber) 

export const fetchByCardNumber = (CardNumber) => dispatch => {
    LoyaltyAPI().fetchByCardNumber(CardNumber)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status !== 200){
                dispatch(Customer(null))
            } else {
                dispatch(Customer(response.data))
            }
        }).catch(error => {
        return error;
    })
}
```

But wherever I have used the url without pathVaribale in axios get call it works.

Eg : `fetchCards: () => axios.get(baseURL+'loyalty/loyaltyCard/all')`
While using the above URL I can dispatch the response to the store and get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the way on dispatching the response to the store. The below code worked.

```
export const fetchByCardNumber = (CardNumber) => dispatch => {
    LoyaltyAPI().fetchByCardNumber(CardNumber)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status !== 200){
                store.dispatch(SelectedCustomer(null))
            } else {
                store.dispatch(SelectedCustomer(response.data))
            }
        }).catch(error => {
        return error;
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//use it like that without curly braces between {cardNumber}

fetchByCardNumber: (CardNumber) => axios.get(baseURL+'loyalty/loyaltyCustomer/card/'+ CardNumber) 

export const fetchByCardNumber = (CardNumber) => dispatch => {
    LoyaltyAPI().fetchByCardNumber(CardNumber)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status !== 200){
                dispatch(Customer(null))
            } else {
                dispatch(Customer(response.data))
            }
        }).catch(error => {
        return error;
    })
}
```

Comment: Actually it was a typo bruh, Still its not working. The issue is on dispatching to the store, not with the URL, as I can console.log the response